# Login Session Cookie Set via Volley

Tags: java, android, session, cookies, android-volley

I'm new on Android & JAVA, I can login with POST but I have to re-login every time when I open the application. Even if I touch the **back** button after the entry, I can return to the login page.

How can I add cookies?

I've found a lot of code and tried them, but I've encountered a error in Android Studio (build)

*Login activity:*

```
package com.example.com

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class GirisAktivitesi extends AppCompatActivity {


    TextView signup, yaziuyegirisi;
    EditText username, userpassword;
    Button btnLogin;

    private static final String loginUrl = "URL";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_giris);
        yaziuyegirisi = findViewById(R.id.yaziuyegirisi);
        username = findViewById(R.id.username);
        userpassword = findViewById(R.id.userpassword);
        signup = findViewById(R.id.usersignup);

        btnLogin = findViewById(R.id.btnUserLogin);



        signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(GirisAktivitesi.this, YeniKayitAktivitesi.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                userLogin();
            }
        });
    }

    public void userLogin() {
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(StringRequest.Method.POST, loginUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {


                try {

                    JSONArray jsonResponse = new JSONArray(response);
                    String registerResultString = jsonResponse.getJSONObject(0).getString("status");
                    String registerMessageString = jsonResponse.getJSONObject(0).getString("message");

                    if (registerResultString.equals("true")) {

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorgulanıyor..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashboardAktivitesi.class); 
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Entered is unfortunately incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>(); 
                params.put("email", username.getText().toString().trim());
                params.put("password", userpassword.getText().toString().trim()); 
                return params;
            }
        };
        Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(request);
    }
}
```

Comment: *I've found a lot of code and tried them* What have you tried then?

Comment: @Tepits I tried to place the cookie but failed.Every time I got an error during build

Comment: Can you share what error did you get? Maybe we can help you fix that error.

Comment: @Tepits I don't hide the codes. I'm trying the code I found on the internet and it is not working back to delete in class page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently using basic authentication method which requires a username and password sent to server every time you need to login. Which forces you to send a login request each time to communicate with the server.

If you need to use an encrypted token to save somewhere and authorize your requests with that you should use [OAuth2](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth2-remember-me) authorization system. This system uses an encrypted **access token** to make authorized requests which is much more secure than saving username and password somewhere in app. And when the token expires you can build a fresh one using the encrypted **refresh token**.

So you technically don't need a new login until the user changes his/her password on another client which will force the user to re-login by the new password the moment you try to use the refresh token to construct a new access token.